# How can I get ValidationMessageFor to work? C# MVC4 Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Model**

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name Required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ViewModelA() { }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(ViewModels.ViewModelA model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do Something Else
    }

    ModelState.Clear();

    return View(model);
}
```

At first, I thought it was because I didn't have `jquery.validate.min.js` or `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` but I included them and it did nothing. Then I tried a mix of `@Html.ValidationSummary()`. Everything I see on stackoverflow says that what I have should work, but it is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have shown works fine assuming you have `jquery`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` loaded correctly (and have not disabled client side validation in your `web.config`file). If you leave the `UserName` textbox blank and click the submit button, the error message will be displayed and the submit cancelled. But why are you doing `ModelState.Clear();` in the POST method and returning the view (that will remove all validation errors)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I want to set a message eventually and the only way for the field to have a value populated from the controller is to use ModelState.Clear(); from what I've been experimenting with.

Comment: Not clear what you trying to do here. Why would you use `ModelState.Clear();`? If you submit and `ModelState` is valid, you save and redirect (and redirect back to the same GET method if you want the same view) or if its not valid, you return the view (without clearing errors) so that the errors are displayed and the user can correct them.

Comment: Like I said, ModelState.Clear() is the only way I have been able to update the fields when returning to the view. If I comment it out it will NOT update anything except the error message. So, if I were to have say a counter starting at 0, first post fail count would increase to 1 if I use ModelState.Clear() but without it count is 0. On second post fail count would increase to 2, but without ModelState.Clear() it is yet again 0.

Comment: You do not change the properties of a model in a POST method and return that 'new' model to the same view. If you want to display different data you follow the PRG pattern and redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - So, say I want to display error messages but also update a field on the page (say Password) for example. Let us say I have UserName, Password, ConfirmPassword fields. If Password and ConfirmPassword do not match I would display an error message and set Password and ConfirmPassword to "". How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Use @Html.PasswordFor()` and return the view (without `ModelState.Clear()` (and I'm assuming you are using the `[Compare]` attribute on `ConfirmPassword`). The `PasswordFor()` method will not use `ModelState` (although if you have implemented client side validation, you would never hit the controller because the submit would be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if your remove `public ViewModelA() { }` does it make it ?

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name Required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //public ViewModelA() { }
}
```

And remove `ModelState.Clear();` too :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(ViewModels.ViewModelA model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do Something Else
    }

    //ModelState.Clear();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does show the ValidationMessageFor, but then I don't get any updates from my model from my controller. For example, if I do model.UserName = "test"; the field does not update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the validation message html helper i.e.

```
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Customer Name")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```